# NSDocumentController not quitting app properly on review unsaved documents in Cocoa/Objective-C

Tags: cocoa

I've been banging my head on walls trying to solve this.

My app uses a subclass of `NSDocument`, `NSDocumentController` and also `NSWindowController`. The issue is that when I create a document and make a modification, and also if I create more than one document the same way, if I choose Quit while documents are unsaved, I get the proper dialogs to ask wether I want to Review unsaved docs, Cancel or Not save, but whenever I select to Review and then save a document, I get to save, but after saving the first document, first, that document is NOT closed, and I am not asked to save the others. On top of this, My App's Quit menu item becomes grayed out.

I created another skeleton app to do the same thing, and of course, all works normally. I checked my connections in the nib file, and cannot see anything wrong, or different from the test app. Although there is a lot more in my app.

I am not currently overriding the `reviewUnsavedDocumentsWithAlertTitle:cancellable:delegate:didReviewAllSelector:contextInfo:` method, but when I do, I get the same problem, since I call Super's version of it after doing some special clean-up work. But again, not overriding this yields the same result.

One thing I do notice, is that in my own App, I get the following messages in the Log as I run it, which I do not get in my test app:

```
[Switching to process 9997 thread 0x7667]
[Switching to process 9997 thread 0x903]
```

Which makes it look like I am doing something multi-threaded here without knowing. My test app doesn't switch to another thread.

I'm not sure how to check if all my connexions are ok and why these threads are being switched to and where they come from.

Since I get the error wether or not I override the `NSDocumentController` methods like the one above or the `closeAllDocumentsWithDelegate:didCloseAllSelector:contextInfo:` I imagine the error comes from somewhere else.

Maybe my `NSDocument` subclass's saving methods are creating the issue, but they return the appropriate values once the save has occurred, I get no error and the files are all fine.

I'd like to override the `-didCloseAllSelector` or `-didReviewAllSelector`, but I'm a bit challenged with this. I'm not sure how to build the method, since this:

```
- (void)documentController:(NSDocumentController *)controller
               didCloseAll:(BOOL)didCloseAll contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
{
NSLog(@"All documents closed");
}
```

is never called. Is this a symptom? Tried the same for the `-didReviewAllSelecter` which never gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was overriding a method in my "NSDocument" subclass which I should not have. Removing this fixed it.

I guess you have to be really careful what you override!

The method was writeToFile:ofType:originalFile:saveOperation: which I no longer had to do.

Not sure exactly what was wrong, but it may help others to know to look there.